# code efficiency, constructing a pivot and transforming to transition matrix with probabilities

Tags: pandas, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to construct a pivot table (later going to turn into transition matrix for Markov Chain). Following is the fake data, that more or less represents the real data. I have over 20 years of data with at least 200 million per year rows.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

## create fake data

```
  newd = {'year': [2001, 2002, 2005, 2002, 2004, 1999, 1999, 1999, 2012, 2000, 2010, 2005, 2006, 2009, 2009, 
                     2009, 2009, 2010, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2000, 2001, 2002],
         'tin': [12, 23, 24, 28,30, 12,7, 12, 12, 23, 24, 7, 12, 35, 39,37, 36, 333, 13, 13, 13, 13, 7, 7, 7],
         'ptin': [12, 23, 28, 22, 12, 12,0, 12, 12, 23, 27, 45, 99, 7, 7, 7, 7, 0, 17, 21, 26, 18, 0, 18, 19] }
```

### few of sampling analysis

newdf=pd.DataFrame(newd)

## group tin by payer's tin

```
df=newdf.groupby(['tin', 'year'])['ptin'].groups

#print(list(df))
#print(np.unique(newdf['year'].values))
```

## using pivot_table function to see the distributions over the years of tin and ptin.

```
print(newdf.pivot_table(index=['tin', 'year'], columns='ptin', values=['ptin', 'tin'], aggfunc=len, fill_value=0))
```

results into

```
ptin      0   7   12  17  18  19  21  22  23  26  27  28  45  99
tin year                                                        
7   1999   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2000   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2001   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2002   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2005   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
12  1999   0   0   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2001   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2006   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
    2012   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
13  2007   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2008   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    2009   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
    2010   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
23  2000   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
    2002   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
24  2005   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
    2010   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
28  2002   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
30  2004   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
35  2009   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
36  2009   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
37  2009   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
39  2009   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
333 2010   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

which is consistent with the dataframe from above.

Now the question is this code efficient if I need to run in billions of rows for three columns? say there would be 6.5 million columns and consistently 200 million rows over years. Has anybody come across this?

Now I am also trying to construct a transition probability of say tin in year x moving from ptin y to ptin z? Any thoughts on that? I know this is too much to ask but heck, I get lot of answers in Stackoverflow. Another strategy I were thinking about was to bin the data, but just dont have idea yet.

Comment: If you want a SQL-based solution, please ask another question, tag with the database you are using, and show the data structures that you have in SQL -- as well as your desired results.

Comment: Gordon Linoff Gordon, actually this is sql based table, datatypes for all fields are NUMERIC. I tagged sql because it might be easier for sql gurus to understand the visual.